# Calculating the minima and maxima of equations involving the trig functions

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

This is the function given:

$$S(x) = \sin^2 x$$

First I calculate the first and second derivatives:

\begin{align}
\frac{dS}{dx}\; & = 2\cos(x)\sin(x) \\
& = \sin(2x) \\
\frac{d^2S}{dx^2}\; & = 2\cos(2x)
\end{align}

Then I find the roots of $S'$:

\begin{align}
& 2\cos(x)\sin(x)\; = 0 \\
& \implies \cos(x)\sin(x) = 0 \\
& \therefore \text{For any}\sin \theta \text{ or} \cos \theta = 0, \text{ we have an extreme point}
\end{align}

Now I know that 
$$\sin \theta = 0\; \forall P\dfrac{\pi}{2}\; \text{where} \dfrac{P}{2} \in I\; i.e\; \text{when }P\text{ is even}$$

and

$$\cos \theta = 0\; \forall P\dfrac{\pi}{2}\; \text{where}\dfrac{P}{2} \notin I\; i.e\; \text{when }P\text{ is odd}$$

At this point I think a little bit. I put the second derivative into a graphing calculator and saw that it is $\gt 0$ for a root of $\sin \theta$ and $\lt 0$ for a root of $\cos \theta$. But I'm not quite sure how exactly to interpret this or how to express it algebraically. I would appreciate some help on how to go forward with finding the minimums and maximums of the original funtion ($S(x)$).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A great deal of machinery for something that can be answered in seconds.

Comment: Why do you need all this stuff? You know that $|\sin x|\le 1$, so it follows immediately that $0\le\sin^2x\le1$. Minimum is attained (inter alia) at $x=0$ and maximum (inter alia) at $x=\pi/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S'(x) = 0$ when $\displaystyle x = 0, \pm \frac{\pi}{2}, \pm \pi, \pm \frac{3\pi}{2}, \dots$

$S''(x) > 0$ when $x = 0, \pm \pi, \pm 2\pi, \pm 3\pi, \dots$

You can express that as $x = n\pi$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ ($n$ is an integer).

$S''(x) < 0$ when $x = \pm \dfrac{\pi}{2}, \pm \dfrac{3\pi}{2}, \pm \dfrac{5\pi}{2}, \dots$

You can express that as $x = \dfrac{(2m+1)\pi}{2}$, where $m \in \mathbb{Z}$.  This works because if $m$ is any integer, then $2m$ is necessarily even, therefore $2m+1$ is odd.  This is a standard way of expressing arbitrary odd numbers.

EDIT:  Based on your comments to this answer, it sounds like you want to be able to explain **why** those inequalities are true and not just generally express their solutions.

First note that $\cos(2x)$ is periodic with period $\pi$.  This means that the value of $2\cos(2x)$ is the same if we add any integer multiple of $\pi$ to $x$ (**not** to $2x$).  Written mathematically, we have $2\cos(2[x + k\pi]) = 2\cos(2x)$ for every integer $k$.  Therefore it's enough for us to just consider the interval $[0,\pi)$ (or any half-open interval of length $\pi$ but let's just keep it simple).

We know that $S'(x) = 0$ when $\displaystyle x = 0, \pm \frac{\pi}{2}, \pm \pi, \pm \frac{3\pi}{2}, \dots$.  Out of all these values, there are only two that reside in the interval $[0, \pi)$.  They are $x = 0$ and $x = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$.  So let's evaluate $2\cos(2x)$ at each of these values of $x$.

$x = 0 \Longrightarrow 2\cos(2 \cdot 0) = 2\cos(0) = 2 > 0$.

Because $\cos(2x)$ has period $\pi$, we know that $2\cos(2[0 + k\pi]) = 2\cos(2 \cdot 0) = 2 > 0$.

But also note that $2\cos(2[0 + k\pi]) = 2\cos(2k\pi)$.

Therefore, $2\cos(2k\pi) > 0$, where $k$ is any integer.

We conclude then that $S''(x) = 2\cos(2x) > 0$ when $x = k\pi$, where $k$ is any integer.

The line of reasoning for $S''(x) < 0$ is identical and I'll leave the details to you.

Comment: So that's how to express it - but how do I prove it? Currently I've written down when $\sin \theta$ is $0$ and when $\cos \theta$ is $0$. Then $S''(0) = 1 \gt 0$, so $S(0)$ is a local minimum. But for the general cases - $S(n\pi)$ and $S((2m + 1)\dfrac{\pi}{2})$, I don't know how I would calculate that.

Comment: $S''(\dfrac{(2m + 1)\pi}{2}) = 2\cos(\dfrac{(4m + 2)\pi}{2})$ - but then I have to prove whether that's $\gt 0$ or $\lt 0$, which is what I'm having trouble with.

Comment: Use periodicity.  There are two cases to check and I worked out the details for one of them.

Comment: Ah! Yes, I understand. Thanks SO much!

Comment: No problem, glad to help!